# Simple question, new student doing practice coursework. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

In the previous lesson, I'm working with let, const, var as well as some comparison operators. Now I get the not equal to, but how would I write out the greater than for the question below?
Thank you!

/ In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: value
// On the next line create a variable called 'greaterThan' and using a comparison operator, check to see if value is greater than 5.
// Assign the results of that to 'greaterThan'

// Please write your answer in the line above.
return greaterThan;
}

Comment: `var greaterThan = value > 5`

Answer (score 0):

`const greaterThan = value > 5;`